# VSCode - Numbers in icon extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code Version 1.56.2 (system setup) and in the extensions panel I see icons that have a number overwritten.
Can you tell me what that number means?

Kind regards

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or describe which icon? Off the top of my head, the explorer panel icon's numbers mean how many unsaved files are in the editor, and for the source control panel's icon's numbers, it's related to the changes you haven't committed (if you are  talking about either of those)

Answer (score 1):

Number (1) are changes waiting to be committed to the git.

Number (27) is total number of extensions installed.

Number next to titles like 2.1.4 are version numbers of extensions.

CMake Tool number (1) ?

**Update:**
That number represents how many other extensions is in Pack (collection) if you click on extension you will see that first Details tab on the top has title *Extension Pack (1)* and then list of all extensions.

[image]

Comment: The last one is the exact one I am trying to figure out as well. Several of my extensions have these numbers,